# Позиция обстоятельства при СГС (переформулирован)

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, порядок-слов, обстоятельство

*После тридцати такие люди обычно одумываются — **по утрам** начинают пить зелёные коктейли, делать зарядку...*

Если интерпретировать предложение следуя только формальным грамматическим и синтаксическим связям, смысл будет такой: после тридцати такие люди каждое утро начинают процесс питья зелёных коктейлей и выполнения зарядки. То есть обстоятельство "по утрам", стоящее перед составным глагольным сказуемым (далее СГС), будет относиться ко всем словам в его составе.

Однако, прочитав/услышав такое предложение, читатель поймёт его самым рациональным способом: после тридцати такие люди начинают каждое утро пить зелёные коктейли и делать зарядку — вводят в свой утренний распорядок эти занятия. То есть читатель отнесёт значение обстоятельства "по утрам" только к инфинитивам в составе СГС — к "пить" и "делать", а к вспомогательному глаголу "начинают" не отнесёт.

**Вопрос**. Позволяют ли нормы русского языка автору — использовать подобный порядок слов, а читателю — интерпретировать предложение указанным образом: относить значение обстоятельства, которое стоит перед составным глагольным сказуемым, только к инфинитиву без отнесения его к вспомогательному глаголу, так как такая интерпретация более рациональна и с наибольшей вероятностью именно она была заложена в предложение автором? Является ли такой порядок слов допустимым только в разговорной речи, то есть в литературной речи следует использовать порядок слов, который допускает только одну интерпретацию (см. пример ниже)?

*После тридцати такие люди обычно одумываются — начинают **по утрам** пить зелёные коктейли, делать зарядку…*

P.S. Вопрос был исправлен из‑за недостатков прошлой формулировки.

Comment: "*Является ли такой порядок слов допустимым только в разговорной речи, то есть в литературной речи следует использовать порядок слов, который допускает только одну интерпретацию*" — всегда нужно так составлять предложение, чтобы была только одна смысловая интерпретация. Зачем путать людей даже в разговорной речи? Последствия недопонимания могут быть значительными.

Comment: @oleedd Я написал об этом в вопросе: люди по смыслу выберут самую рациональную интерпретацию и поймут всё правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Оно изначально воспринимается в правильном смысле:

*по утрам начинают пить коктейли* = *начинают по утрам пить коктейли*.

Но если посидеть пару минут и вдуматься, то проявляется второе значение: *по утрам начинают пить, но не факт, что допивают до конца*. Такая интерпретация довольно странна для данного предложения.

Примечание: в подобных случаях изначально будет восприниматься самый рациональный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Формальная грамматика устанавливает следующий **нейтральный порядок слов**: начинают пить (что?) коктейли (когда?) по утрам. (Сначала прямое дополнение, потом обстоятельство).

Но при **актуализации предложения** порядок слов может меняться, если автор хочет логически выделить какое-то слово. Актуализация не является нарушением грамматики или стилистики, поэтому здесь **нет речи о разговорном стиле.**

Правильным является вариант 1: ***После тридцати обычно одумываются, по утрАм начинают пить зелёные коктейли, делать зарядку.***

В этом случае обстоятельство ***по утрам*** выделено логическим ударением и поэтому оно является общим  для сказуемых, то есть по утрам начинают пить, по утрам начинают делать зарядку.

Таким образом, говорящий интуитивно выбирает **такой порядок слов, который нужен для правильного понимания смысла предложения** в том случае, если формальная грамматика с этой задачей не справляется однозначно.

Актуализация, правильная интонация — это такие же (необходимые и полноценные) ***инструменты*** в нашей речи, как и грамматически связи.

Comment: Соотнесённость обстоятельства "по утрам" с обоими инфинитивами, входящими в состав сказуемого, не вызывает сомнений. Вопрос заключается в другом. По смыслу "по утрам" должно относится только к "пить зелёные коктейли" и "делать зарядку", а с точки зрения грамматики захватывает ещё и "начинают", поэтому задуманный говорящим смысл искажается. Во втором абзаце моего вопроса я указал как именно.

Comment: Не вижу никакого искажения смысла. Рассмотрим прямой порядок слов: люди начинают пить зеленые коктейли по утрам.  Смысл единственный -  вводят в свой утренний рацион. А как можно еще понять?  Начинают пить  по утрам и заканчивают вечером? Это вряд ли .Поэтому перестановка слов ничего не меняет в общем смысле, но зато выполняет выделительную функцию,что тоже очень важно. Поэтому не разговорная это речь, а  грамотная и правильная.

Comment: "А как можно еще понять?" При прямом порядке слов верно — никак, смысл единственный: вводят в свой утренний рацион. А вот если "…по утрам начинают пить…", то можно понять как "каждое утро начинают процесс питья". Конечно, это бессмысленно, но по грамматике получается именно так: обстоятельство перед сказуемым, значит относится ко всему составу сказуемого. Или обстоятельство, находящееся перед сказуемым, может относиться не ко всему составу, а только к инфинитиву (в данном случае — однородным инфинитивам)? Вот на этот вопрос хочется получить ответ.

Comment: При актуальном членении предложения мы меняем порядок слов. А что к чему тогда относится? Это определяется по грамматическим связям, по логическим ударениям, по смыслу.  Грамматика русской речи дает нам такую возможность.

Comment: Понял вас. Тогда не могли бы поправить свой ответ, потому как в нём вы ответили на немного другой вопрос: является ли "по утрам" общим для двух инфинитивов, а вопрос был про отношение "по утрам" ко всему составу сказуемого либо только к инфинитивам?

Comment: И подчеркнуть, что при актуальном членении обстоятельство, находящееся перед СГС, может относиться не ко всему составу СГС, а только к инфинитиву, и что в данном случае такое соотношение определяется смыслом.

Comment: Я лучше так скажу. Существуют члены предложения, которые являются детерминантами. Они относятся не к конкретному слову, а ко всему предложению, то есть к его грамматической основе. Часто детерминанты являются обстоятельствами времени или места и находятся в начале предложения. Определяются детерминанты не только по   позиции, но и по смыслу, в частности этому способствует их логическое выделение ударением.

Comment: Но в нашем предложении «по утрам» точно не детерминант, поскольку не относится ко всему предложению, а относится только к **части СГС** — однородным инфинитивам.

Comment: Вы слишком бегло прочли мои комментарии и немного не уловили смысл :) Но вам простительно — вы на столько вопросов в день отвечаете)

Comment: Пожалуй, нет,  ничего простительного для себя я не вижу. Как говорится, лучше меньше, да лучше. Дело в том, что мы просто плохо понимаем друг друга.  Обычно ваши комментарии я долго и "тупо" читаю, пытаясь понять ваши представления, ваш ход мыслей. Надо признаться, они кажутся мне весьма необычными.   К примеру, чтобы нам с вами совместно рассуждать о детерминантах, нужно хотя бы иметь общее мнение о том, как они определяются (в современном  синтаксисе). Вы же рассуждаете о детерминантах так, будто всё о них знаете, как будто это вообще ваша специальность.

Comment: Честно говоря, беседы с вами вызывают у меня неоднозначные эмоции: вы мне и нравитесь немного, и вызываете чувство недоумения и любопытства. Вы смешиваете грамматику и интонацию, письменную и устную речь  в нечто единое, в чем сложно разобраться. К примеру, интонационный анализ еще не имеет хорошо разработанной практической школы (есть только отдельные  элементы), поэтому пользоваться им надо аккуратно, ваши же суждения кажутся мне излишне смелыми. Это гибкая система, а вы делаете из нее жестко формальную.

Comment: Я изо всех стил стараюсь излагать свои мысли так, чтобы мы с вами друг друга понимали. Дело в том, что вы ответили не на то вопрос, который я задал. А вопрос важный. Я уверен, что вы сможете на него грамотно  ответить — если мне удастся донести, в чём он состоял. Давайте перейдём в чат, чтобы не засорять комментарии.

Comment: Мне не нравится разговаривать в чате, я себя чувствую там неуютно.  Если вопрос так важен для вас, попробуйте его задать еще раз на форуме, изменив формулировку. Тогда у вас будет больше возможностей для того,  чтобы получить на него грамотный ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 1):

***После тридцати такие люди обычно одумываются — по утрам начинают пить зелёные коктейли, делать зарядку...***

**В качестве вступления**

**Семантика** — это то **содержание**, которое мы хотим передать в нашей речи.  Делаем  мы это, выбирая подходящую форму: **грамматику и структуру предложения,  а также правильную лексику.**  Так задается основной смысл сказанного  (это как бы рисунок предложения).

**А как же порядок слов, расстановка логических ударений, интонация?** Эти факторы могут **корректировать смысл**, если  грамматика определяет его **неоднозначно**.  Но такое происходит не слишком  часто.

Поэтому основное назначение интонационной структуры предложения — это **сделать речь удобной для восприятия, подчеркнуть главную мысль, расставить акценты** (мы как бы подбираем краски для нашего рисунка, **не меняя его основной части**).

**Решение задачи**

А теперь обратимся к исходному предложению и зададим себе вопрос: **а была ли в нем неоднозначность, с которой не справились лексика и грамматика?**

1) Прежде всего здесь следует обратить внимание на глагол ***начать***.

**НАЧАТЬ,** св. 1. что и с инф. **Приступить к какому-л. действию**. Н. лекцию, репетицию, арию, обед. Н. учить уроки, купаться, пахать землю. 2. с инф. **Проявить первые признаки какого-л. действия или состояния.** Вода начала заливать лодку.  Начали зажигаться огни в домах.

Два первых значения глагола отличаются между собой, но правильный выбор  делается **по  контексту.** Здесь подходит **второе значение:** начинаем (**регулярно!**)  пить коктейль и делать зарядку (проявляем **первые признаки действия).**  Выбор значения сделан, **и никакой порядок слов его не изменит.**

2) Но это еще не всё, так как в этом предложении была **еще одна проблема со смысловой неоднозначностью.** Чтобы понять это, рассмотрим прямой порядок слов во второй части предложения: ...*(они) начинают пить зелёные коктейли, делать зарядку по утрам.*

При таком порядке слов можно видеть **две смысловые неточности**: коктейли пьются не по утрам, а вообще; зарядка же делается именно по утрам, а не как раньше (в любое время).

И это как раз тот вопрос, который не может решить грамматика. Поэтому используется инверсия: обстоятельство переносится в начало предложения и на правах детерминанта оно относится к обоим однородным членам и устраняет обе смысловые неточности. Таким образом, при актуальном членении предложения **уточняется смысл,** заданный грамматическими связями (**уточняется, но не определяется!**).

**Немного о порядке слов**

Понятие  **прямого порядка** слов в русском языке существует, но при актуальном членении предложения он **постоянно нарушается**, и это важное свойство русской речи.

Мы можем это делать, так как  **основной смысл уже задан грамматикой.** При изменении порядка слов, при расстановке логических ударений передается **дополнительная информация**, но при этом базовое содержание, заданное грамматикой, сохраняется.

**Вывод**

Поэтому читатель всё поймёт **верно и рационально**: после тридцати такие люди  вводят в свой утренний распорядок указанные  занятия.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) На мой взгляд, второе значение глагола "начать" не подходит. Посмотрите на примеры — везде субъект неодушевленный и действие инициируется не субъектом, а происходит само по себе. А в словаре Ушакова и вовсе написано не "действие", а "явление": *2. с инф. Проявить первые признаки какого-нибудь **явления**, состояния. Начало смеркаться. Отец начал стареть*.

Comment: Но давайте даже закроем глаза на это. Возьмём указанный в словаре пример второго значения: «Начали зажигаться огни в домах». Переделаем его под нашу структуру: «Каждый вечер огни начинают зажигаться в домах». Смысл — «каждый вечер огни в домах проявляют первые признаки зажигания», каждый вечер заново, по‑новому. Огни не **вводят в свой режим процесс зажигания каждый вечер**, следовательно и люди тоже не **вводят в свой утренний распорядок указанные занятия** при выборе такого значения глагола «начать».

Comment: Вы пишите: *Здесь подходит второе значение: начинаем (регулярно!) пить коктейль и делать зарядку (проявляем первые признаки действия)*. Как раз этого ***регулярно!*** второе значение глагола «начать» не предполагает.